# Unable to unload driver after setting DeviceObject flags

Tags: c++, driver, wdk, wdm

I've got a problem with driver unload function. Because I use **MmGetSystemAddressForMdlSafe** function I had to set DeviceObject Flags to DO_DIRECT_IO. (**DeviceObject->Flags = DO_DIRECT_IO**). This pointer is causing a lot of trouble in my code, because I cannot unload my driver correctly. In WinDbg I can see that unload function is being called correctly. It's removing Symboliclink but for unknown reason to me, it's not removing DeviceObject from Windows objects. **IoDeleteDevice(DriverObject->DeviceObject)** I can see in Winobjects that DeviceObject still exists (only Symboliclink gets removed) and my .sys file is still loaded in System process even after unloading the driver. How am I suppose to unload my driver after pointing **DeviceObject->Flags = DO_DIRECT_IO**? My goal is to unload driver correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of **DeviceObject->Flags = DO_DIRECT_IO**, I had to set **DeviceObject->Flags |= DO_DIRECT_IO;**